# Access VBA - qdf parameters item not found - error 3265

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I can't seem to understand what I've done wrong here. I'm getting an error 3265 (Item not found in this collection) at the three lines starting with "qdf.Parameters..."   My understanding is that I define the where clause of my sql statement here, but maybe I'm wrong? Pretty new to vba with access so a little confused.

```
Sub Save_Invoices_Meet_Criteria()

Dim FileName As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim myStmt As String
Dim Db As DAO.Database
Dim myrs As DAO.Recordset

Set Db = CurrentDb()

Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = Db.QueryDefs("qryCreateInvoicesApproved")

qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Invoice_approved]") = [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Invoice_approved]
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![invoice_date]") = [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Combo272]
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Invoice_Type}") = [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Combo274]

Set myrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct [reference] from qryCreateInvoicesApproved", 2)

Do Until myrs.EOF

FileName = Me.reference
foldername = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")
FilePath = "C:\Users\company\Desktop\Invoicing Database\Save_Test\" & foldername & "\" & FileName & ".pdf"

DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTInvoice", acFormatPDF, FilePath
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, FilePath



DoCmd.Close
myrs.MoveNext

Loop

myrs.Close
Set myrs = Nothing

End Sub
```

My sql statement:

```
SELECT tblAccountingDatabase.*
FROM tblAccountingDatabase
WHERE (((tblAccountingDatabase.Invoice_approved)=Yes) And ((tblAccountingDatabase.invoice_date)=Forms!frmAccountingDatabaseInput!Combo272) And ((tblAccountingDatabase.Invoice_Type)=Forms!frmAccountingDatabaseInput!Combo274));
```

Comment: You just need to read up on Parameter Queries and using querydefs. You have to define your parameters in `qryCreateInvoicesApproved` and then use the actual parameter names defined in the query. It looks like you're trying to use some type of hybrid parameters based on your form's recordset???

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a `PARAMETERS` line at the beginning of your stored query which you then reference in the VBA querydef object. Then use the [Querydef.OpenRecordset()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822070.aspx) method to pass parameterized query into a recordset object. Right now you are passing named parameters that do not exist:

**SQL**

```sql
PARAMETERS [Approveparam] YesNo, [Dateparam] Datetime, [Typeparam] String;
SELECT DISTINCT [reference]
FROM tblAccountingDatabase
WHERE (((tblAccountingDatabase.Invoice_approved) = [Approveparam]) 
  AND ((tblAccountingDatabase.invoice_date) = [Dateparam]) 
  AND ((tblAccountingDatabase.Invoice_Type) = [Typeparam]));
```

**VBA**

```vb
...
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = Db.QueryDefs("qryCreateInvoicesApproved")

qdf!Approveparam = [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Invoice_approved]
qdf!Dateparam = [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Combo272]
qdf!Typeparam = [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Combo274]

Set myrs = qdf.OpenRecordset()
...
```

To pass parameters to a form/report/macro that uses the same paramterized query use [DoCmd.SetParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194182.aspx) method. And yes, you need to wrap every value with quotes hence the quote escaping. Also use [DoCmd.OutputTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx) to convert report to PDF:

```
DoCmd.SetParameter "Approveparam", _
            """" & [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Invoice_approved] & """"
DoCmd.SetParameter "Dateparam", _
            """" & [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Combo272] & """"
DoCmd.SetParameter "Typeparam", _
            """" & [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Combo274] & """"

DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTInvoice", acViewPreview
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "RPTInvoice", acFormatPDF, FilePath
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this - When I try running it I get a dialogue box asking my to input parameters for Approveparam, dateparam, typeparam. These are supposed to already be defined in frmDatabaseInput

Comment: How are your running the query? From SQL window or VBA code? Is the form opened when you *run it* with non-null values?

Comment: Well, I thought the vba ran the query, and the query depends on values from frmAccountingDatabaseInput, invoiceapproved, combo272, combo 274. Then, the form is where I run the VBA from - I select the invoice date (dateparam), select an invoice type (typeparam), and am left with a few matching records (table is displayed). The goal is to save those few records to my desktop as a pdf. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Correct. VBA calls this parameterized query and passes those form values automatically to the named parameters. It should not prompt you. Did you include the parameters line in query? Is the appropriate query name included in VBA, `qryCreateInvoicesApproved`? Do data types align?

Comment: OK I realized that this step is actually working fine. It is later in the code - `DoCmd.OpenReport "RPTInvoice", acFormatPDF, FilePath` - where it is asking me to input parameters. "RPTInvoice" is the PDF layout of the records. It also calls the values in the query

Comment: See update using `DoCmd.SetParameter`. Also OpenReport does not convert to PDF. You need to use `DoCmd.OutputTo`.

Comment: That works for those three fields, but I'm now prompted for the other fields of the record that were not filtered

Comment: Then add all named parameters accordingly. But if you are being prompted for non-params then your query is referencing fields not in any `FROM` or `JOIN` table of query.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of looks like you're trying to force yourself to use a parameter query but not really committed to it. If you don't want to truly use one you can change your SQL structure to use generic parameter names - and then use the `qdf.Parameters` method to fill the values from your form.

But I think this is the easiest for what you have now.

**Replace these lines:**

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = Db.QueryDefs("qryCreateInvoicesApproved")

qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Invoice_approved]") = [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Invoice_approved]
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![invoice_date]") = [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Combo272]
qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Invoice_Type}") = [Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Combo274]

Set myrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct [reference] from qryCreateInvoicesApproved", 2)
```

**With this line to open your recordset**

`Set myrs = qdf.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from qryCreateInvoicesApproved", 2)`

**Change your query to:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [reference]
FROM tblAccountingDatabase
WHERE (tblAccountingDatabase.Invoice_approved=[Forms]![frmAccountingDatabaseInput]![Invoice_approved]) 
AND (tblAccountingDatabase.invoice_date=Forms!frmAccountingDatabaseInput!Combo272) 
AND (tblAccountingDatabase.Invoice_Type=Forms!frmAccountingDatabaseInput!Combo274);
```

Comment: You're right with changing it to db - or currentdb. You might need to change it into a parameter query when runnng from recordset code. Use @Parfaits's code below

Comment: The line you had me insert gives me an "object required" error. I think it's because qdf is not defined? I changed that to "Db.openrecordset(...)" but now I get an error saying "Too few parameters. Expected 3."

Comment: I tried @parfait 's code as well - That query has me input values when I try to run the code, but the values already exist in the form. When I change the first part of the where clause of your query to say "WHERE (tblAccountingDatabase.Invoice_approved= Yes", the expected parameters reduces to two. So I think the error is in the where clause - it just doesn't like the way I'm referencing the combo272 and 274